# Booting from flash, can't escape grub rescue

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue

I recently wanted to reinstall Ubuntu on a partition on my PC. I used Gparted to delete the partition so that I could start fresh. I tried to boot to the usb, but it went into grub rescue mode. I looked at other solutions on here, and tried the whole ls->set root->reboot method, I tried it on each partition on the hard drive, to no avail. I then tried loading grub onto the flash drive and booting to that, no change. Then I reinstalled Gparted, and still nothing, I'm just stuck in grub rescue. I am at the end of my rope here, anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your system boots to the harddrive but fails. When you say "boot to the usb", is that Ubuntu Live on a USB stick? If that doesn't work, have you tried burning a Ubuntu Live CD and booting from it?